# Derivative of log of multivariate Normal respect to Matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, normal-distribution, vector-analysis

I am wondering how to calculate the gradient of a multivariate Normal respect to L where  $\Sigma=LL^{T}$. I know what would be the derivative respect to $\Sigma$ and I can use chain rule to get the derivative respect to L but since $\Sigma$ is a matrix and L is matrix then derivative of a matrix respect to matrix is 4D tensor.

Therefore I am wondering can anyone help to find the derivative of

log|L|$-(x-z)L^{-1}L^{-T}(x-z)^{T}$ respect to L. The first term involving the determinant is a standard calculation but I am stuck  in the second term.

Answer (score 2):

In matrix calculus it is often easier to use *differentials* instead of the chain rule, since it avoids the need to calculate third and fourth order tensors.

Define the variables
$$A = LL^T,\quad y = x-z$$
Note that
$$A^T=A,\quad A^{-1} = L^{-T}L^{-1} $$
Write the cost function in terms of these new variables.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log(\det(L)) + y^TA^{-1}y \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= d\log(\det(L)) + y^TdA^{-1}y  \\
&= d{\,\rm tr}(\log(L)) + {\rm tr}\big(y^TdA^{-1}y\big) \\
&= {\rm tr}\Big(d\log(L) - y^TA^{-1}dA\,A^{-1}y\Big) \\
&={\rm tr}\Big(L^{-1}dL-y^TA^{-1}dL\,L^TA^{-1}y-y^TA^{-1}L\,dL^T\,A^{-1}y\Big) \\
&={\rm tr}\Big(L^{-1}dL-2L^TA^{-1}yy^TA^{-1}dL\Big) \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial L}
 &= L^{-1} - 2L^TA^{-1}yy^TA^{-1} \\
 &= L^{-1} - 2L^{-1}yy^TL^{-T}L^{-1} \\
}$$
Depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), you may want the *transpose* of this result.